# How can I surface-mount (PVC conduit) light fixtures and ceiling fans?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, conduit

**Background:**

I'm currently in the middle of rewiring my house, largely because it's an older house (vintage 1939), and between multiple rewirings and the oldest wiring still in use being original, we have some glitchy circuits, we don't have enough receptacles, and the layouts don't really make sense. Also, once I audited them, we had a *lot* of breakers in the box powering circuits that didn't match to *anything* we could find. Eep!

As such, I'm redoing the whole house with individual circuits for each room, power and lighting separated, with a couple of additional circuits for major appliances, with the intent of disconnecting all the existing wiring and pulling out everything we can access. Because there are issues with some of the walls, we quite like the look, and it's good for accessibility, we're doing all the new wiring in surface-mounted PVC conduit.

**Question:**

I'm doing the power circuits first, which are going well, but once those are done, we'll be on to the lighting. I may have made the bad assumption here that I should be able to obtain an equivalent surface-mount box to the existing in-wall boxes that would accept a light fixture or ceiling fan in the same way, but I thus far haven't been able to track such a thing down.

Am I making a bad assumption? If not, I could use some advice on what I should use to do this job; if so, I could use some advice on how, if possible, I should go about the job of surface-mounting light fixtures and ceiling fans in a conduit-compatible way.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

It occurred to me that this might be easier; in every case except for the two ceiling fans, we're going to be replacing the fixtures too, so what we'll need is a surface-mount box compatible with this fixture:

[image: Top]
[image: Bottom]
[image: Bottom (w/o tape)]

Comment: Pictures, including a ruler or section of measuring tape, of the boxes you are trying to replace would be helpful. Otherwise this is stunningly vague, as we don't know what boxes you have that you can't find replacments for. Please [edit] those in. Though I'd venture to guess that a fan-rated surface mount box might indeed be a unicorn.

Comment: I'll see what I can do. (It's a little tricky in some cases because of lights we're still using, etc., but I'll see what can be done.)

Comment: If they are all the same, pictures of one will do. If they are all different, you can edit more than once as you get to them.

Comment: Thought the quickest way might be to post the new fixtures we want to use with the new boxes, since we're replacing them in every case but the ceiling fans. I'll work on getting the ceiling fans down tomorrow and get pictures of their boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want are [Non-metalic surface mount boxes](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-4-in-Round-Non-Metallic-Weatherproof-Box-with-5-1-2-in-Holes-White-WRB550PW/300851124?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD-71700000110012104-58700008378060397-92700076247463580&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAjMKqBhCgARIsAPDgWlzoM3hx6mHk026dfHt1lZxok4SrCiMcRqv9uHtj624dO50WfO6qVvEaAgUwEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). (just an example, google "PVC surface mount electric boxes.)

They are available in multiple designs for different applications.

You will have to be responsible for proper mounting to support a fan or light fixture.